# PHP UPLOAD_ERR_OK, but no file in the temporary directory

Tags: php, linux, file-upload, file-permissions

Using HTML form, I try to upload file into server.
The code is running fine in XAMMPP on my Windows (file uploaded to temporary directory and move to desired directory) but when I upload the code into Linux/Apache webserver, it produce UPLOAD_ERR_OK but there is no file in temporary directory.

**form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**upload.php (Example from w3school)**

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

echo json_encode($_FILES);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

I believe this problem does not related to the script itself, rather it is problem in directory permission.

In **php.ini**

```
file_uploads = On
;upload_tmp_dir = 
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_file_uploads = 20
```

If **echo the $_FILES** (`echo json_encode($_FILES);`), it show this:

```
{"fileupload":
      {"name":"rectify2222.zip",
       "type":"application\/x-zip-compressed",
       "tmp_name":"\/tmp\/phpaXKMXW",
       "error":0,
       "size":540941
      }
}
```

Check on **phpinfo()**

| Directive | Local Value | Master Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| upload_tmp_dir | /tmp | /tmp |

**Tmp Directory Properties**

| . | . |
| --- | --- |
| directory | /tmp |
| Group | root(0) |
| Owner | root(0) |
| Permission | 1777 |

I have try the following
**#1 CHANGE FOLDER PERMISSION**
I have try change folder permission to 0755, 0777, 1777, 7777 (with recursive) but still does not work

**#2 CHANGE OWNERSHIP OF THE DIRECTORY**
I have try change ownership of the folder directory to www-data but does not work
`chown www-data:www-data /tmp`

**#3 CHANGE GROUP FOR THAT DIRECTORY**
I have try change ownership of the folder directory to www-data but does not work

```
sudo groupadd newgroup
usermod -a -G newgroup root
usermod -a -G newgroup www-data
usermod -a -G newgroup nobody
chgrp -R newgroup /tmp
chmod -R 755 myfiles
```

**#4 CREATE NEW DIRECTORY AND CHANGE IT UPLOAD TMP DIR**
I have try create new directory call **`/tmp2`** with permission **0777**.
Then, I change `upload_tmp_dir` in **php.ini**
`upload_tmp_dir =/tmp2`
run the script, but the file still not there..

Is there anything I should do or configure. Hope you can help me.
I'm still beginner..